# A Mac build host was not automatically detected, Windows 8

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've Windows 8 and I'm trying to develop iphone application. I've downloaded and installed xamarin with ios development tools, started the visual studio 2012. So when I'am trying to create ios project, the window appears with message: "A Mac build host was not automatically detected". Can anybody help me? I searched the answer for a long time but did not succeed, thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin for Visual Studio still requires a Mac on the same network in order to build the app itself. iOS apps can't be built on Windows, currently.

From: http://xamarin.com/visual-studio

> [...] with a networked Mac providing the build and deployment services.